# Why isn't a new activity instance created?

Tags: android

I have one simple activity which just logs the life cycle:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("hello", "onCreate")
        Log.d("hello", this.toString())
    }
    override fun onStart(){
        super.onStart()
        Log.d("hello", "onStart")
    }
    override fun onResume(){
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("hello", "onResume")
    }
    override fun onPause(){
        super.onPause()
        Log.d("hello", "onPause")
    }
    override fun onStop(){
        super.onStop()
        Log.d("hello", "onStop")
    }
    override fun onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("hello", "onDestroy")
    }
}
```

I ran this app on a device with API 30 then pressed overview button and swiped the app up to kill the process. Logcat shows the following:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (10930) for package com.example.viewmodel ----------------------------
2023-12-13 14:32:06.935 10930-10930 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onCreate
2023-12-13 14:32:06.935 10930-10930 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  com.example.viewmodel.MainActivity@2edf7d9
2023-12-13 14:32:07.010 10930-10930 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onStart
2023-12-13 14:32:07.084 10930-10930 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onResume
2023-12-13 14:32:10.573 10930-10930 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onPause
2023-12-13 14:32:10.994 10930-10930 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onStop
2023-12-13 14:32:11.634 10930-10930 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onDestroy
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (10930) for package com.example.viewmodel ----------------------------
```

As you can see `onDestroy` method was called which implies that the instance of the Activity was killed. Then i start the app again from the launcher expecting to see other value from `Log.d("hello", this.toString())`, but for some reason i get exactly the same value:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (10983) for package com.example.viewmodel ----------------------------
2023-12-13 14:41:01.475 10983-10983 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onCreate
2023-12-13 14:41:01.475 10983-10983 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  com.example.viewmodel.MainActivity@2edf7d9
2023-12-13 14:41:01.541 10983-10983 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onStart
2023-12-13 14:41:01.604 10983-10983 hello                   com.example.viewmodel                D  onResume
```

**Why isn't a new instance of the activity created after `onDestroy` call ?**

Answer (score 1):

As you can see "*@2edf7d9*" is always the same "memory pointer", so the Activity is not re-instantiated but just recovered from "cache"/memory. It avoid the need to reallock memory and do a completly new instantiation when a lot of RAM is still available.
It's all well explained in "Activity lifecycle" section of Android Guides....

Comment: thanks for the reply. I couldn't find any about this thing in "Activity lifecycle" section. Could you tell where exactly it is

Comment: About Activity Lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=en
For the REASON why the Object/Activity is reteined in memory, you have to read something more "deep" about Java and/or Android Memory Management documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You got new app process (with different PID) so there's no way it's the same class instance.

Identity hashcode clash (`@2edf7d9`) doesn't mean much in this case.

Comment: Heap memory is retained/reserved/cached for that specific Application, so a PID or TID could be different but the Object could be restored from its "shared" Heap.

Comment: @emandt what does object restoration imply? Because it we had incrementing counter in onCreate there's no way it would ever print more than 0.

Comment: I don't think to have understood the part of "print more than 0" and the prev one about "incrementing counter".....Android rarely kills an Activity and re-instantiate it completly from scratch. It depends of how much memory is still available, how that Application/Activity manages its Instances (an attribute in Manifest) and finally it depends of how the Activity is implemented/used.

Comment: @emandt I don't know what you're imagining here. We are seeing activity being killed here, once it passed `onDestroy` it won't be reused ever even within same process, much less across them. Whether there are some internal jvm optimizations that keep classes loaded in memory is irrelevant for how you should design your code.

Comment: a destroyed Activity doesn't mean anything from a memory POV. Destroyed doesn't means "freed memory" in Java. In fact if you check Heap memory (using Profiles or MemoryDump feature) you will see that that Activity are still in memory. Destroyed has a meaning only for Lifecycle but not for Memory POV. Like a detached Window is not destroyed but just "removed from its parent".

Comment: @emandt `using Profiles or MemoryDump feature` Profiles is profiler in android studio ? If it is, how did you manage to find out that the activity is still in memory ? After closing the app, profiler stops working because the process has been killed.